Mystery daily Explorer popup window trying to view my my boot partition
Something is mounting my boot partition (the 100MB partition with the Windows boot loader) as drive I: and opening it in Windows Explorer, leaving an Access denied error popup. It happens every day. I don't think it's malware, but how do I catch the culprit responsible? My suspicion is it's my backup program, Macrium Reflect, but I'm not certain.

Simply put, remove the drive letter for the ESP (EFI System Partition), not exactly a "boot" partition (but contains the Windows Bootloader Manager .efi files indeed) like it's often seen in Linux servers, alongside their own ESP.

I've already removed the drive letter many times.

You can try

Task Manager.
Open task manager, > startup apps. make a right click on the header (where there's name, publisher Etc.) and click on "command line" now you will see a new column with the command line it does at startup.

Auturuns by sysinternals.
download auturuns here and run to see everything that runs at start up.



if it is the backup see here for this issue
https://forum.macrium.com/32887/RE-Access-denied-error-message-for-FAT32-SYSTEM-drive#32890
